# clicking on rep score while in meta leads to "page missing" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta

If I click on my total reputation score in the status bar next to my username *while in meta*, I get to a "missing page" page. In the parent site I get to a page that explains my privileges, and the ones I do not (yet) have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been removed from child metas.